# The wider meaning of 'consider' and 'take into account'

Tags: grammar

Many dictionary entries state that *consider* and *take into account* can be used to mention things that need to be thought of when reaching a decision.

Can I infer from this that I can also use these words to mention only those things that cannot be ignored whilst doing something and thus, take somehow an active part in the action?

An example would be:

*The sensor was adjusted to the simulation conditions by considering only response times that can be found in experiments.*

'By' is here the means of achieving something (https://www.lexico.com/definition/by). **I know there are many ways to express this**, but I would like to use 'consider' or 'take into account' to state things that are relevant to the success of the action.

Another example would be:

*I cook the dish and take only spices from the Middle East into account = I cook the dish by taking only spices from the Middle East into account.*

Comment: Consider limits its action to "thinking about something." "Taking into account" implies that the action will be/is/has been done. In your example, I would only use "taking into account".

Comment: The words are not absolute synonyms. One way to take spices into account would be to see what you have in the kitchen. Thinking about adding cumin to a dish is not taking that spice into account, that's considering it. Another distinction: "Take into account that, if are considering cumin, your perspiration takes on that aroma."

Comment: Introducing “only” to expressions that are not specific and restrictive obviously makes them specific and restrictive. I’m not clear what your question is. Your example sentences aren’t very helpful because they seem unnatural.

Comment: I wanted to use „consider“ and „take into account“ in the sense of „pay attention to/not ignoring“. In the last example sentence, I wanted to express that I basically used only spices from the Middle East because I ignored the rest, or in other words, I had only spices from the Middle East in my mind. Obviously, when I want to achieve something, I think about how I can do it. Therefore, I need to think about things that help me do so. If I ignore things in my thinking, these things can‘t help me in achieving what I want to do, hence I do not „use“ the things. Make sense?